# БазИлика или базилИка?

Tags: фонетика

С детства произносил слово "базилика" с ударением на втором И (живу в Крыму, и подобные архитектурные сооружения, точнее, их руины, у нас тут не редкость), потом услышал, что везде говорят "базИлика". Долго переучивался. Почти переучился.
И тут мне в интернете попадается информация, что правильно говорить все-таки "базилИка". Подскажите, кто прав и нужно ли мне продолжать переучиваться дальше или возвращаться к первоначальному произношению?)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Резниченко (2009) указываются две формы: базИлика и базилИка. Слово греческого происхождения, но заимствовано из латинского языка с ударением на втором слоге (базИлика).

Вариантность ударение можно видеть на примере поэтических текстов:

"И, как во сне родные тени, Встречал я с радостной тоской БазИлик рухнувших ступени И плиты древней мостовой" (В.Брюсов).

"И прах веков упал на прах святынь. На славный город, ныне полудикий. И вой собак звучит тоской пустынь Под византийской ветхой базилИкой (И. Бунин).

Answer (score 2):

Согласно словарям возможны оба варианта ударения. 
БАЗ*И*ЛИКА; БАЗИЛ*И*КА, -и; ж. [от греч. basilikē - царский дом, дворец]. Архит.
Античный и средневековый тип постройки (обычно храм) в виде удлинённого прямоугольника с двумя продольными рядами колонн внутри, расчленяющими пространство на три помещения. Византийские базилики.
(Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова)